# Does traffic exchange software that automatically visits network sites in the background affect SEO?

Tags: seo, traffic, web-traffic

Does traffic exchange software like JingLing affect SEO?  Traffic exchange software controls your web browser and automatically visits sites in exchange for other people running the software visiting your site.

I am only asking in terms of SEO, and not if its good for earnings or not. I am aware that it's dead traffic with high bounce rate.

I ask because I've seen that when my site received traffic through Google ads, SEO has skyrocketed. It helped me rank well for many keywords. Based on this, my assumption is that traffic helps SEO.

Will JingLink help SEO?

Comment: Alexa rank does not affect Google's ranking algorithms - https://www.seroundtable.com/amazon-alexa-rank-google-search-rankings-28045.html. I'm not sure if the same can be said for other search engine rankings. Good content and linking is going to do a whole lot more for SEO than fake traffic.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Direct traffic does nothing for SEO if that is what you are asking. Cheers!!

Comment: @tshimkus Thanks for the generic answer, Neither I asked about good content and linking nor I ever talked about Alexa rank. My question is very straight forward if you notice

Comment: @closetnoc is it possible for you to quote any source or studies ? As I said from my own experience, I saw direct traffic did effect in SEO .

Comment: Thank you for your very kind words. You did ask what kind of traffic would help and the answer is real traffic from real users. In short the answer is no, page visits from bots have absolutely no positive effect on search rankings. Google will use direct traffic data collected from Chrome browser in its ranking analysis so direct visits _can_ help, but only when using Google's ecosystem. It's the same reason clickthrough from Google Ads helped your ranking. They do not use Google Analytics as these are configured by site owners and could be prone to tampering if it was a factor.

Comment: Only traffic through the SERPs effect SEO. Direct traffic cannot. How is a search engine to know about direct traffic? It cannot. There are some side effects of some direct traffic, however, buying traffic is usually junk traffic.

Comment: @tshimkus  sorry but I just tried on an article and it ranked quickly